# A 2d matrix can be reconstructed, in which a mask has been used with numpy where and flattened

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

As the question says I have a 2D matrix (1000, 2000), in which I apply a condition with the numpy where function, in this way:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randn(1000, 2000)
print(A.shape)
(1000, 2000)
mask = np.where((A >=0.1) & (A <= 0.5))

A = A[mask]
print(A.shape)
(303112,)
```

and I get a flattened matrix which I use as input in a Fortran program which only supports 1D matrices, the output of this program has the same dimension as the input 1D matrix **(303112,)**,  is there any method or function to reconstruct the flattened matrix to its original 2D form. I was thinking of saving the indexes in a boolean matrix and use these to reconstruct the matrix, if someone knows of any numpy method or any suggestion would be of great help.

Greetings.

Comment: In order to get a boolean matrix, you could try: `np.logical_and(A >= 0.1, A <= 0.5)`, let me know if I need to be more explicit

Comment: You need to maintain the 1D and 2D version of indexes that are there in the mask. Essentially you want to turn the 2D mask into 1D, do your processing. then get the 2D indexes back from the 1D mask. You can use `np.ravel_multi_index` to get 1D indexes and use these 1D indexes to get back the original 2D indexes using `np.unravel_index`, check my answer for details.

Comment: Does `res[mask]= new_values` work, where `res` has the desired 2d shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need to maintain the 1D indexes and 2D indexes of the mask so that when you try to update those values using a FORTRAN program, you can switch to 1D for input and then switch back to 2D to update the original array.

You can use `np.ravel_multi_index` to convert 2D indexes to 1D. Then you can use these 1D indexes to convert them back to 2D using `np.unravel_index` (though since you already have the 2D mask, you don't need to convert 1D to 2D again.)

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randn(1000, 2000)
mask = np.where((A >=0.1) & (A <= 0.5))

idx_flat = np.ravel_multi_index(mask, (1000,2000)) #FLAT 1D indexes using original mask
idx_2d = np.unravel_index(idx_flat, (1000,2000))   #2D INDEXES using the FLAT 1D indexes


#Comparing the method of using flat indexes and A[mask]
print(np.allclose(A.ravel()[idx_flat],A[mask])) 
### True

#Comparing the freshly created 2d indexes to the original mask
print(np.allclose(idx_2d,mask))
### True
```

---

Here is a dummy test case with end to end code for a (3,3) matrix.

```
import numpy as np

#Dummy matrix A and mask
A = np.random.randn(3, 3)  #<---- shape (3,3)
mask = np.where(A <= 0.5)
mask[0].shape  #Number of indexes in 2D mask
###Output: (6,)

#########################################################

#Flatten 2D indexes to 1D
idx_flat = np.ravel_multi_index(mask, (3,3)) #<--- shape (3,3)
idx_flat.shape  #Number of indexes in flattened mask
###Output: (6,)

#########################################################

#Feed the 6 length array to fortran function
def fortran_function(x):
    return x**2

flat_array = A.ravel()[idx_flat]
fortran_output = fortran_function(flat_array)

#Number of values in fortran_output
fortran_output.shape
###Output: (6,)

#########################################################

#Create a empty array 
new_arr = np.empty((3,3))  #<---- shape (3,3)
new_arr[:] = np.nan
new_arr[mask] = fortran_output   #Feed the 1D array to the 2D masked empty array

new_arr
```

```
array([[5.63399114e-04,            nan, 7.86255167e-01],
       [3.94992857e+00, 4.88932044e-02, 2.45489069e+00],
       [3.51957270e-02,            nan,            nan]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers , but the input matrix in the FORTRAN program can only be a 1D matrix with the range of values (>=0.1 and <=0. 5), according to the example 303112 values meet the condition so the input matrix would be this, so I can not enter a flattened 1D matrix of 1000x2000 as processing times are too high, plus out of range values that produce an error in the program, the idea would be to save the indices where the condition is met and as the original matrix is always of the form (1000, 2000) assign to the matrix values in the corresponding indices and the rest assign a NAN.

Comment: 1D matrix here is not 1000X2000, its 303112 still

Comment: You are just maintaining the 303112 indexes separately

Comment: i have updated my code to be more informative with a step by step example for a (3,3) matrix.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the example, it has helped me to clarify the problem, I had obtained good results using lists by compression, replacing values where the boolean array was TRUE but it was a less efficient approach, so I appreciate your help.